# ModelBuilder and Delete fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, fields-attributes, list

I like to know if there is a solution to the following problem. I currently have a simple ModelBuilder workflow in which includes a list of shapefiles being copied. Within the workflow, once copied, I  would like to batch delete fields from the copied files, but for some reason I am unable to perform such task. When I open up the delete field tool, I am only able to select the first row. The rest are all greyed out (disabled)

I have attached two images as reference.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Shapefile you can only delete (single delete) one feature set.

[image]

Or use Iterate with Feature Datasets (Geodatabase)

Delete Fields

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004n000000

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would avoid the batch tool approach. Create a sub-model and cycle through the datasets using an iterator deleting the fields as necessary.